# Clear the content of panel

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I want to clear the content of panel. This is my code to create panel.

```
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
```

Now when I press the back button and again content of panel is not remove and new content append the previous content.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your using jQuery you can use `$('#panel').empty()` to clear the content within.